# US Citizen living in Sweden--Visa required to visit Turkey for one week with family?

Tags: visas, turkey

I am living in Sweden, but am an American Citizen with an American Passport.  Myself and my Swedish family are going to Alanya Turkey for one week on a family vacation.  My Swedish family does not require a visa, however do I need one?  I do possess Swedish identification.

Comment: So get one. What do you want to know? i can't see any question here.

Comment: You clearly need a visa (http://turkey.usembassy.gov/visa_requirements.html)

Answer (score 7):

US Citizens do indeed require a visa to visit Turkey, whilst Swedish citizens do not (for a stay of up to 90 days).

Unlike some countries, Turkey visas are little more than a fee payment - at least when purchased on arrival.  In purchasing multiple of them I've never had them even look at my passport beyond opening it to a blank page and sticking in the visa.

Historically Turkey has offered "Visa On Arrival" for most nationalities, where you simply paid the fee on arrival at a special booth and were given your visa stamp. However they are in the process of moving towards e-Visas where the visa is requested/issued online.  They had previously announced that visas-on-arrival would no longer be available from earlier this year, however they have since reversed that decision at least in some airports, but started charging more for a visa-on-arrival to encourage people to buy them in advance.

Thus your options as a US Citizen are to either [apply for an e-Visa on their website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/) which will require a credit card and cost US$20, or apply for a Visa-On-Arrival at the airport which must be paid in cash and will cost US$30.

I would strongly suggest going the eVisa route - not only does it mean a shorter wait at the airport, but it also removes any risk around the possibility they will stop issuing visas-on-arrival before your trip, or that your point of entry will not offer them.

Comment: The last paragraph does not make sense, do you mean “going the e-visa route”?

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is all so new to me, as I have not needed a Visa for Germany or Czech Republic.  We just thought about this after we bought the tickets.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Annoyingly, travel agencies don't seem to have that kind of information available anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as an American Citizen with an American issued Passport, you will need an entry visa to enter the Republic of Turkey. According the [Visa Requirements page](http://turkey.usembassy.gov/visa_requirements.html) you should be able to purchase one at your port of entry into Turkey for $30 USD. You will be able to stay for up to 90 days and will not be able to re-enter again for an additional 90 days beyond the initial 90 day limit.

The fact that the rest of your family do not need a visa, are Swedish citizens and that you are currently living in Sweden yourself have no bearing on your need for a visa.

Comment: The page you have linked to is incorrect.  Visa-on-Arrival costs US$30, whilst the recommend e-visa costs only US$20.